# Cannot create a new project in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, maven-3

I installed OpenJDK, Maven and NetBeans, but when I try to create a new Java project with Maven I get an error that says that `cannot enable Spring Beans`. This is the full error message.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed this and the issue was solved https://www.howtoinstall.me/ubuntu/18-04/libspring-beans-java/